# How to write a floating point in using binary notation instead of decimal?

Tags: matlab

A floating point is usually given in decimal notation, e.g. 1.25.  However for binary the same value could be 1.01.

It is possible to use such binary notation to specify floating point values in MATLAB?

Comment: That is not how binary floating point works *at all*. You are looking at fixed point arithmetic

Comment: Seems you are looking for `num2hex` function.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: How come that real numbers (float) can only be written using decimal notation, and not binary notation?  If it is valid to give a float in decimal notation as 1.25, then it should be just as valid to give it in binary notation as 1.01, e.g. 0b1.01 or hexadecimal notation like 1.4, e.g. 0x1.4.  Might be that different programs does not support it, but extending from integer notation in different bases to float notation in different bases is obvious.

Comment: I think you are just confusing terms which is what @AnderBiguri is referring to.   "floats" generally mean IEEE-754 representation.  What you are asking for called "fixed point" not "float".  http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/sp06/handout/fixedpt.html

Comment: @AeroEngy: Thanks for the comment, and the link.  The intention is actually to write a model using MATLAB float, and later implemented it in hardware using fixed point.

Comment: Sounds like the Matlab's Fixed Point Designer toolbox might be of use.  I don't have a license for that so can't provide any help there ... just thought I would pass it along.   "Fixed-Point Designer™ provides data types and tools for developing fixed-point and single-precision algorithms to optimize performance on embedded hardware." 
  https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Ander Biguri said that is not floating point ([IEEE-754 double see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

However, if you want to represent binary the way you suggest in your question you could do something the example below.  In my example you have to specify how many bits you want to represent the binary integer & fractional portions and it outputs as a char array:

```
num2Convert = 1.25;
numInt  = 5; %Number of bits for interger portion
numFrac = 5; %Number of bits for fraction portion
dInt  = num2cell(fix(rem(num2Convert*pow2(-numInt+1:0),2)));
% More simply you could just do dec2bin(fix(num2convert)); for the int portion...
% but I wanted to be consistent with the fractional portion
dFrac = num2cell(fix(rem( rem(num2Convert,1)*pow2(1:numFrac),2)));
binString = [sprintf('%d',dInt{:}),'.',sprintf('%d',dFrac{:})]

binString =
00001.01000
```

Now if you want to see the binary representation of the underlying double precision float you could do this:

```
binString  = dec2bin(typecast(num2Convert,'uint64'),64)

binString  =
0011111111110100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```